# surfaces are being cut off

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, scaling

I read [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2937/why-is-my-plot-cut-off), [that](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/65734/some-parts-of-curves-are-being-cut-off-by-the-frame-in-my-multiple-curve-plot) and some others. However, I could not get it why some of my surfaces are being cut off (probably due to scaling). Here is what I have:

```
Plot3D[Table[ (10^-7*t)*(i /w)^2, {t, {1.17, 1.38, 1.56, 2.34, 2.9, 4.12, 4.76}}]
       // Evaluate, {i, $MachineEpsilon, 0.0001}, {w, 20*^-9, 100*^-9},
       PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.2], Mesh -> False, ClippingStyle -> None, PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image: my plot]

Can someone show me the tricks to get better coloring and more distinguished surfaces. I'm coming from R and was hoping for a better result.

Comment: Well, `Opacity[0.2]` certainly made them look anemic. Try with `PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.7], Glow[Black]]` and  (probably more importantly) `PlotRange -> All`. (For reference, could you post a picture of what it might look like in R?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `PlotRange->All`

```
Plot3D[Table[(10^-7*t)*(i/w)^2,{t,{1.17,1.38,1.56,2.34,2.9,4.12,4.76}}]
   //Evaluate,{i,$MachineEpsilon,0.0001},{w,20*^-9,100*^-9},
   PlotStyle->Opacity[0.2],Mesh->False,ClippingStyle->None,
   PlotPoints->50,
   PlotRange->All (*added this*)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Mathematica has some heuristics which uses to decide the most pleasing/optimal
plot range to use if none are given.

Comment: Now that I see the ful range. I'm like it is a nice heuristic! Would you help me with other sub-questions. Unfortunately, I cannot upvote (due to low rank) but I can mark your solution as an answer. Appreciate it.

Comment: Particularly, if possible, each curve has a different interval on "w". I could not find a solution.

Comment: @JohnButler if I can answer the other question(s) will try. They seem unrelated to the cut-off issue.

Comment: @John, the "different intervals" question seems unrelated, so do ask a new question. Please don't forget to supply those required intervals for each surface should you do so.

Comment: @J.M.There you go, man. Thanks! https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/155722/different-intervals-in-3d-plot-of-multiple-surfs